# I pushed an element into an Array[0] position, however, it did not turned out as I intended. My element ended up at position Array[1], not Array[0]

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

My output goal was this: `[[4, 1]]`

```
const num1 = [[1]];
num1[0].push(4);

console.log(num1); //result is [[1, 4]];
```

Comment: You are looking for `unshift` instead of `push`.

Comment: ah, that was a silly mistake. thanks!

Comment: I thought that when I specify the index of num1[0], it would function hm....

Comment: That index only specifies which *array* you want to modify, not *what* the modification will be.

Comment: Thank you, now I get it